# Apply column name change to a list of data frames but the changes were not reflected in the original data frames

Tags: r

I have 4 data frames and each data frame has 5 columns.

```html
> birch
           hutt.hr.date hutt.hr.BLT10m hutt.hr.BLRH hutt.hr.BLwd hutt.hr.BLws
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00      15.383333     78.02500   317.000000   4.51666667
2   2015-01-01 01:00:00      15.133333     78.08333   308.333333   3.99166667
3   2015-01-01 02:00:00      14.808333     76.60833   297.333333   3.30833333

> mssgc
           hutt.hr.date hutt.hr.MSSGCT10m hutt.hr.MSSGCRH hutt.hr.MSSGCwd hutt.hr.MSSGCws
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00          17.15000        78.03333        17.16667       2.4166667
2   2015-01-01 01:00:00          16.88333        76.45000        15.83333       1.9750000
3   2015-01-01 02:00:00          16.50833        75.63333       120.41667       1.3083333

> uhsp
           hutt.hr.date hutt.hr.UHSPT10m hutt.hr.UHSPRH hutt.hr.UHSPwd hutt.hr.UHSPws
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00        16.391667       74.24167      322.41667      3.0083333
2   2015-01-01 01:00:00        16.241667       72.95833      291.00000      2.2166667
3   2015-01-01 02:00:00        15.816667       72.35000      325.83333      3.7666667

> wbc
           hutt.hr.date hutt.hr.WBCT10m hutt.hr.WBCRH hutt.hr.WBCwd hutt.hr.WBCws
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00       15.966667      79.30833     208.33333     5.3250000
2   2015-01-01 01:00:00       15.541667      79.88333     266.33333     5.1916667
3   2015-01-01 02:00:00       15.166667      78.62500     287.33333     3.4500000
```

I want to rename their column names by first putting all 4 data frames into a list, then use lapply to rename their columns.

```html
df < -list(birch, mssgc, uhsp, wbc)

df < -lapply(df, function(x) {
  colnames(x) < -c("date", "Temp", "RH", "Wdir10m", "Wspeed10m")
  x
})
```

After that i tried applying list2env to unlist the list again but failed..

```html
list2env(df,.GlobalEnv)
```

How do I make changes to a list of data frames where the original data frames will have the changes made?

Thank you for you time and help!

Comment: A couple of issues. 1) You have a typo in your code whenever you're using the assignment arrow - `< -` instead of `<-` Other than that your `lapply` code is fine. I think the issue with `list2env` is because you don't have a "named list", like `df <- list(birch=birch, mssgc=mssgc, uhsp=uhsp, wbc=wbc)` to start with. There is probably little reason to work with free-floating datasets though, since they are all the same structure. Either store them in a list continually, or flatten them all to one big dataset with an identifier column.

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail your suggestion works! i added list(birch=birch, mssgc=mssgc, uhsp=uhsp,wbc=wbc) and it worked. What does it mean to add the name of the data frame again (eg, birch=birch)?

Comment: It just names each part of the list after the source dataset. Look at `names(df)` to see what I mean.